# Compression Image

Tags: lossless-compression

I am having SQL Server2005 Database where half of the data is Image which isin various formats.
I want to convert all the image into jpeg2000 format and want to resize(reduce the size) the Images also.
The front end application is made on VC++/MFC which is displaying all the images on the dialogues.

Please provide guidence for how to change images into jpeg2000 and how reduce the size

Answer (score 0):

You can google and find any number of Jpeg2000 compressors / sdk.  Some are free, some are not.

You can expect some reduction in file size just by compressing to JP2, even if you encode losslessly.  There are many different encoding options with JP2, you'll want to do some testing before commencing you conversion enmasse.

If you provide a little more description of what your specific requirements are we may be able to provide more specific guidance.
- what kind of images are they (8.5 x 11 bitonal images?  50 GB high-res 4 band satellite images?) 
- what are the input formats?
- how big are they?
- how will they be used after they are compressed (rendered by what?  streamed to what? analyzed by what?)
- does it need to be lossless?

### ...